# R/dplyr Get running maximum value

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have below data

| CODE | TIME | VALUE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ABC | 1 | 40 |
| ABC | 2 | 50 |
| ABC | 3 | 30 |
| ABC | 4 | 60 |

I am trying to find the maximum `VALUE` until a given timepoint.
For example, for `TIME == 2` and `TIME == 3`, `MAXVALUE` should be 50.

For `TIME == 4` `MAXVALUE` should be 60.

I trying to get below table,

| CODE | TIME | VALUE | MAXVALUE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ABC | 1 | 40 | 40 |
| ABC | 2 | 50 | 50 |
| ABC | 3 | 30 | 50 |
| ABC | 4 | 60 | 60 |

Please suggest how can I do in R using `dplyr`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can simply use `cummax`:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  arrange(time) %>%
  mutate(maxvalue = cummax(value))
```